Showing all authors names in the first citation
I am having trouble to make all authors' names appear in the first citation of a given piece. In Oveleaf, I am using natbib with the longnamesfirst option with the apalike biblio style. Below I leave an MWE. Any help would be much appreciated.
\documentclass[12pt,english]{article}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{bib.bib}
@article{hotz2018,
  title  = "Parenthood, Family Friendly Workplaces, and the Gender Gaps in Early Work Careers",
  author = "Hotz, V. Joseph and Johansson, Per and Karimi, Arizo",
  year   = "2018",
  journal= {NBER Working Paper No. 24173}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[authoryear,round,longnamesfirst]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
%%\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.25}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.25}

\begin{document}
\citet{hotz2018} % this should list all three authors

\citet{hotz2018} % ok to truncate the author list the second time a piece is cited

\bibliography{bib}
\end{document}


Unfortunately, the apalike bibliography style, which is one of BibTeX’s original styles, is not versatile enough to work with natbib’s longnamesfirst option. And, being more than 40 years old by now, the apalike bib style in no way generates formatted  entries that resemble modern APA requirements. I suggest you switch from natbib/apalike to apacite/apacite.

Many thanks for your answer, it worked in Overleaf. Apart from this, I am trying to make it work in Textmaker, but the compiler is not able to find the citations. For every citation, it throws an error saying: Citation`reference' on page X undefined. I would appreciate it if you knew why this happens. Best.

Please clarify what you mean by "it worked in Overleaf". Do you mean that making the switch to the apacite citation management package and the apacite bibliography style is "working"? Please advise.

Also off-topic: The geometry option list left=1in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in may be expressed more succinctly as margin=1in. And it's simply wrong to use the @article entry type for, say, the hotz2018 entry. Why aren't you using the @techreport entry type here?

Many thanks for your comments, I will take them into account for the future. Yes, I made the switch to apacite and it worked. Now, I am trying to run the same code in Texmaker 6.0.0., but it seems that it does not do the trick. Any idea? Thanks!!

Incidentally, I've taken the liberty of making your sample code truly minimal. Feel free to revert.

I think the changes are ok and help other users, thanks. I think the distribution is MikTex, if that is what you are asking for?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

(summarizing the information in the comments, so that this query may be considered to have received an answer)
Unfortunately, the venerable apalike bibliography style, which is one of BibTeX’s original styles, is not versatile enough to work with natbib’s longnamesfirst option. And, being more than 40 years old by now, the apalike biblio style in no way generates formatted entries that resemble current APA requirements.
I suggest you switch from
\usepackage[authoryear,round,longnamesfirst]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}

to
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}

Actually, this will "only" get you to the 6th edition of the APA formatting requirements for bibliographic entries and the associated citation call-outs. If you must satisfy the current, i.e., 7th, edition of the APA requirements, you'll need to make a bigger switch, to biblatex (with the apa "style") and biber. There are several postings on this site that explain how to accomplish this switch.
Regarding your follow-up question: While the Overleaf platform automatically performs a call to BibTeX (if needed) during a compilation run, that's not the case for many other platforms. Since you're using TeXmaker as the front end (and MikTeX as the back end, right?), you will need to run BibTeX yourself between LaTeX runs. See the TeXmaker documentation for information on how to make a BibTeX run.
A final comment: You really should make a habit of not using incorrect entry types. For sure, for the hotz2018 entry, you ought to be using the @techreport entry type, not the @article entry type. The latter should only ever be used for pieces published in scholarly journals.


\documentclass[12pt,english]{article}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{bib.bib}
@techreport{hotz2018,
  title = "Parenthood, Family Friendly Workplaces, and the Gender Gaps in Early Work Careers",
  author = "Hotz, V. Joseph and Johansson, Per and Karimi, Arizo",
  year = "2018",
  institution = "National Bureau of Economic Research",
  type = "Working Paper",
  number = "24173",
}
\end{filecontents}

%\usepackage[authoryear,round,longnamesfirst]{natbib}
%\bibliographystyle{apalike}

\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
%%\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.25}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.25}
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\citet{hotz2018} % list all three authors on first citation

\citet{hotz2018} % ok to truncate the author list now

\bibliography{bib}
\end{document}


Many thanks for your answer. Regarding the Texmaker issue, I usually do the process of runs pdflatex>bibtex>pdflatex>pdflatex, but it still throws the error:  Citation `reference' on page X undefined on input line XX.

@RubénPérezSanz - This looks like a new question to me. I see you've indeed posted a follow-up query, Apacite not working in Texmaker, in the meantime. Would you say the new issue is solved for now?

Yes it is solved!! thanks!!
